# explorer.exe memory usage is high when deleting files

Tags: c#, explorer

I have an application running constantly on my server.

I start off a thread which goes into an infinite loop.

The 1st thing this loop does is enumerate directories in a certain folder.

This folder has many sub-folder that receives small image files from many clients.

My loop looks for any directories/files that are older than say 24hrs from today's immediate time /date.

If it is older then my code deletes the files and the parent folder.

My loop will then 'sleep' for 60 seconds before repeating again.

Now, what I have noticed is that if there is a large number of files to delete or/and the app has been running for several days the explorer.exe memory increases significantly.

So, I have to question my code.

This is my code:

```
Thread thArchiver = null;
private void btnArchiver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (btnArchiver.Text == "Start")
        {
            btnArchiver.Text = "Stop";
            lvwServices.Items[4].SubItems[1].Text = "Started";
            thArchiver = new Thread(ArchiveWorker);
            thArchiver.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            btnArchiver.Text = "Start";
            lvwServices.Items[4].SubItems[1].Text = "Stopped";
            thArchiver.Abort();

        }

    }
    catch { }
}

 private void ArchiveWorker()
 {
     while (true)
     {
         try
         {
             List<string> catDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(CataloguePath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
             for (int index = 0; index < catDirs.Count; index++)
             {
                 //look at time of creation and then delete the directory
                 Directory.Delete(catDirs[index]);
             }
         }                     
         catch (Exception _ex)
         {
          //report the error
         }
         Thread.Sleep(60000);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You should use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Is the `explorer.exe` process your application, or is it the windows explorer process?

Comment: Hi Maarten. thanks for your attention. I was referring to the windows explorer.exe process - thanks :)

Comment: Use SysInternals' Autoruns utility and disable shell extensions that were not written by Microsoft.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi, just noticed your advice.  I will have to a look into this to see what it all means. Will report back here.  Thanks :)

Comment: I have done as you suggested but the only non-software in the explorer tab was winrar - which I have now disabled.  But I doubt if that will have much impact. Useful app though - thanks

Comment: @closer Hi, This is about code.  I want to know if my code is causing the explorer.exe process to go high in memory usage and if so whether there is an alternative way to do this.  Could you explain what your thoughts are? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much possible!

Reasons can be as your thread sleeps for 60 sec only

```
List<string> catDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(CataloguePath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
```

And you are creating list in every new thread so what is happening is that the list of folders and its reference is stored again and again.
And this is a never ending process so it will keep going on and on and size increases.
This get stored in memory so you see this lag.

what I suggest is:
Don't open new thread and put a check that last thread is completed or not.

Update:
Possible reason as per comments by @Andrew and @Maarten

```
List<string> catDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(CataloguePath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
             for (int index = 0; index < catDirs.Count; index++)
             {
                 //look at time of creation and then delete the directory
                 Directory.Delete(catDirs[index]);
             }
```

I feel the Forloop is taking time  because what might be happening is 
Directory.Delete(catDirs[index]); starts a new thread itself no what might be happening is there is lot of files to get deleted in queue and queue increases day by day.
Thats might be the reason you are seeing lag

Comment: If the reference of the list of the first iteration is overwritten by the reference of the list of the second iteration of the loop, then the first list is orphaned, which means it is up for clean-up by the garbage collector. So that doesn't explain the memory usage. And why would a 60s loop explain memory-usage?

Comment: @nipun. Hi thanks for looking at this. The thread is only created once.  Then the loop takes over.